# I ran into a problem using Elastic Beanstalk from aws

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a problem. I checking my database connection, and i was using this application on my localhost, and it was okay. but when i deploy this web application, i always facing 502 error. i was tried modify security group and etc, but it never work. and i get a some last 100 line log message from elastic beanstalk log, so if you can solve problem, plz help me. thank you.

this is the log.

```
    enter code here ----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
----------------------------------------
2021/01/06 07:23:24 [error] 3544#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 222.108.35.81, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "couponservice-env.eba-7apfigmx.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2021/01/06 07:23:24 [error] 3544#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 222.108.35.81, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "couponservice-env.eba-7apfigmx.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://couponservice-env.eba-7apfigmx.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2021/01/06 07:24:50 [error] 3544#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 222.108.35.81, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "couponservice-env.eba-7apfigmx.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2021/01/06 07:24:50 [error] 3544#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 222.108.35.81, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "couponservice-env.eba-7apfigmx.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://couponservice-env.eba-7apfigmx.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2021/01/06 07:25:11 [error] 3544#0: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 222.108.35.81, server: , request: "POST /couponapi/coupons HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/couponapi/coupons", host: "couponservice-env.eba-7apfigmx.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"


----------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-engine.log
----------------------------------------
2021/01/06 07:21:09.211870 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
2021/01/06 07:21:09.216802 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active healthd.service
2021/01/06 07:21:09.220123 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start healthd.service
2021/01/06 07:21:09.259532 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/healthd/healthd_logformat.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/healthd_logformat.conf
2021/01/06 07:21:09.260732 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/healthd/healthd_nginx.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/healthd.conf
2021/01/06 07:21:09.262012 [INFO] Executing instruction: configure log streaming
2021/01/06 07:21:09.262023 [INFO] log streaming is not enabled
2021/01/06 07:21:09.262027 [INFO] disable log stream
2021/01/06 07:21:09.262046 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service
2021/01/06 07:21:09.270643 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service
2021/01/06 07:21:09.281164 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetToggleForceRotate
2021/01/06 07:21:09.281181 [INFO] Checking if logs need forced rotation
2021/01/06 07:21:09.281203 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-northeast-2:908803455527:stack/awseb-e-parj2s23pb-stack/810a0e30-4fef-11eb-ab7d-02ea5112e8c2 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region ap-northeast-2
2021/01/06 07:21:09.852882 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-northeast-2:908803455527:stack/awseb-e-parj2s23pb-stack/810a0e30-4fef-11eb-ab7d-02ea5112e8c2 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region ap-northeast-2
2021/01/06 07:21:10.418675 [INFO] Generating rsyslog config from Procfile
2021/01/06 07:21:10.420226 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl restart rsyslog.service
2021/01/06 07:21:10.437082 [INFO] Executing instruction: PostBuildEbExtension
2021/01/06 07:21:10.437101 [INFO] Starting executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild.
2021/01/06 07:21:10.437120 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-northeast-2:908803455527:stack/awseb-e-parj2s23pb-stack/810a0e30-4fef-11eb-ab7d-02ea5112e8c2 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region ap-northeast-2 --configsets Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2021/01/06 07:21:10.805240 [INFO] Finished executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild.

2021/01/06 07:21:10.805258 [INFO] Executing instruction: CleanEbExtensions
2021/01/06 07:21:10.805287 [INFO] Cleaned ebextensions subdirectories from app staging directory.
2021/01/06 07:21:10.805292 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreDeployHooks
2021/01/06 07:21:10.805300 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/predeploy/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2021/01/06 07:21:10.805316 [INFO] Executing instruction: stop X-Ray
2021/01/06 07:21:10.805320 [INFO] stop X-Ray ...
2021/01/06 07:21:10.805343 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf xray.service
2021/01/06 07:21:10.811931 [WARN] stopProcess Warning: process xray is not registered 
2021/01/06 07:21:10.811961 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop xray.service
2021/01/06 07:21:10.819094 [INFO] Executing instruction: stop proxy
2021/01/06 07:21:10.819116 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf httpd.service
2021/01/06 07:21:10.823306 [WARN] deregisterProcess Warning: process httpd is not registered, skipping...

2021/01/06 07:21:10.823337 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2021/01/06 07:21:10.829206 [WARN] deregisterProcess Warning: process nginx is not registered, skipping...

2021/01/06 07:21:10.829230 [INFO] Executing instruction: FlipApplication
2021/01/06 07:21:10.829235 [INFO] Fetching environment variables...
2021/01/06 07:21:10.829325 [INFO] Purge old process...
2021/01/06 07:21:10.829370 [INFO] Register application processes...
2021/01/06 07:21:10.829376 [INFO] Registering the proc: web

2021/01/06 07:21:10.829389 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf web.service
2021/01/06 07:21:10.835429 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2021/01/06 07:21:10.908738 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2021/01/06 07:21:10.912741 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-enabled eb-app.target
2021/01/06 07:21:10.916222 [INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/aws-eb.target to /etc/systemd/system/eb-app.target
2021/01/06 07:21:10.917734 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable eb-app.target
2021/01/06 07:21:11.000983 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start eb-app.target
2021/01/06 07:21:11.006200 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable web.service
2021/01/06 07:21:11.093044 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf web.service
2021/01/06 07:21:11.097989 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active web.service
2021/01/06 07:21:11.101314 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start web.service
2021/01/06 07:21:11.115896 [INFO] Executing instruction: start X-Ray
2021/01/06 07:21:11.115910 [INFO] X-Ray is not enabled.
2021/01/06 07:21:11.115915 [INFO] Executing instruction: start proxy with new configuration
2021/01/06 07:21:11.115939 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /var/proxy/staging/nginx/nginx.conf
2021/01/06 07:21:11.136081 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c cp -rp /var/proxy/staging/nginx/* /etc/nginx
2021/01/06 07:21:11.139384 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2021/01/06 07:21:11.147234 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
2021/01/06 07:21:11.235279 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
2021/01/06 07:21:11.244986 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf nginx.service
2021/01/06 07:21:11.254903 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active nginx.service
2021/01/06 07:21:11.262544 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start nginx.service
2021/01/06 07:21:11.344371 [INFO] Executing instruction: configureSqsd
2021/01/06 07:21:11.344388 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip configure sqsd daemon ...
2021/01/06 07:21:11.344393 [INFO] Executing instruction: startSqsd
2021/01/06 07:21:11.344397 [INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip start sqsd daemon ...
2021/01/06 07:21:11.344401 [INFO] Executing instruction: Track pids in healthd
2021/01/06 07:21:11.344405 [INFO] This is an enhanced health env...
2021/01/06 07:21:11.344424 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf aws-eb.target | cut -d= -f2
2021/01/06 07:21:11.359446 [INFO] cfn-hup.service healthd.service nginx.service

2021/01/06 07:21:11.359494 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p ConsistsOf eb-app.target | cut -d= -f2
2021/01/06 07:21:11.378785 [INFO] web.service

2021/01/06 07:21:11.378913 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPostDeployHooks
2021/01/06 07:21:11.378925 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2021/01/06 07:21:11.378930 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/01/06 07:21:11.379030 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"SUCCESS","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"SUCCESS","msg":"Engine execution has succeeded.","returncode":0,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment successfully detected a JAR file in your source bundle.","timestamp":1609917668,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment successfully generated a 'Procfile'.","timestamp":1609917668,"severity":"INFO"},{"msg":"Instance deployment completed successfully.","timestamp":1609917671,"severity":"INFO"}]}]}

2021/01/06 07:21:11.379165 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy

2021/01/06 07:25:23.304531 [INFO] Starting...
2021/01/06 07:25:23.304584 [INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
2021/01/06 07:25:23.304608 [INFO] reading event message file
2021/01/06 07:25:23.304721 [INFO] no eb envtier info file found, skip loading env tier info.
2021/01/06 07:25:23.304787 [INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec

2021/01/06 07:25:23.422026 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-northeast-2:908803455527:stack/awseb-e-parj2s23pb-stack/810a0e30-4fef-11eb-ab7d-02ea5112e8c2 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region ap-northeast-2
2021/01/06 07:25:24.160493 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-northeast-2:908803455527:stack/awseb-e-parj2s23pb-stack/810a0e30-4fef-11eb-ab7d-02ea5112e8c2 -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region ap-northeast-2
2021/01/06 07:25:24.503333 [INFO] checking whether command tail-log is applicable to this instance...
2021/01/06 07:25:24.503346 [INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
2021/01/06 07:25:24.503350 [INFO] Engine command: (tail-log)

2021/01/06 07:25:24.503401 [INFO] Executing instruction: GetTailLogs
2021/01/06 07:25:24.503406 [INFO] Tail Logs...
2021/01/06 07:25:24.503660 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/error.log
2021/01/06 07:25:24.505286 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c tail -n 100 /var/log/eb-engine.log


----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: ... 57 common frames omitted
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: ... 60 common frames omitted
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:16.273  WARN 4145 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:16.278  WARN 4145 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:16.284  INFO 4145 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:16.319  INFO 4145 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:16.330 ERROR 4145 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.6.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at com.bharath.springcloud.CouponserviceApplication.main(CouponserviceApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[application.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[application.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[application.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[application.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar!/:5.4.12.Final]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
Jan  6 07:25:16 ip-172-31-11-100 web: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]

Jan  6 07:25:18 ip-172-31-11-100 web: .   ____          _            __ _ _
Jan  6 07:25:18 ip-172-31-11-100 web: /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
Jan  6 07:25:18 ip-172-31-11-100 web: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
Jan  6 07:25:18 ip-172-31-11-100 web: \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
Jan  6 07:25:18 ip-172-31-11-100 web: '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
Jan  6 07:25:18 ip-172-31-11-100 web: =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
Jan  6 07:25:18 ip-172-31-11-100 web: :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)
Jan  6 07:25:18 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:18.835  INFO 4172 --- [           main] c.b.s.CouponserviceApplication           : Starting CouponserviceApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on ip-172-31-11-100.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal with PID 4172 (/var/app/current/application.jar started by webapp in /var/app/current)
Jan  6 07:25:18 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:18.842  INFO 4172 --- [           main] c.b.s.CouponserviceApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
Jan  6 07:25:20 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:20.430  INFO 4172 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
Jan  6 07:25:20 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:20.561  INFO 4172 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 111ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
Jan  6 07:25:22 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:22.185  INFO 4172 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9091 (http)
Jan  6 07:25:22 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:22.212  INFO 4172 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
Jan  6 07:25:22 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:22.218  INFO 4172 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
Jan  6 07:25:22 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:22.399  INFO 4172 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Jan  6 07:25:22 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:22.400  INFO 4172 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3432 ms
Jan  6 07:25:23 ip-172-31-11-100 web: 2021-01-06 07:25:23.440  INFO 4172 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...


----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
----------------------------------------
222.108.35.81 - - [06/Jan/2021:07:23:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" "-"
222.108.35.81 - - [06/Jan/2021:07:23:24 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://couponservice-env.eba-7apfigmx.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
```

Comment: Can you clarify - the issue is with db connection? Also is this RDS database?

Comment: Yes. it is RDS database. and i dont know exactly what is it, but i just guess it's a db connection issue.

Comment: Can you ssh to the EB instance, and maybe just try using `mysql` (or whatever db you use) client manually to check connectivity to the rds? This way you will know if the issue is instance wide, or just specific to your app.

Comment: Typically means that the IP address of Elastic Beanstalk has not been set in the Inbound Rules. As a test - try opening up the Inbound rules to everyone and see if that connection works. Then you will know this is the issue to focus on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like Inbound Rules issue. In the AWS tutorial that uses a web application that uses AWS RDS, Inbound Rules are mentioned. You need to make sure the IP address of the Elastic Beanstalk instance is specified. If you do not do this, then the connection does not work.

Here is the AWS RDS tutorial that discusses this subject matter:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_rds_item_tracker